# JSch Equivalent or Similar for Windows

Tags: java, wmi, wmic

I am trying to make a service that can remote into a box and run a few commands. I have one for linux boxes that I wrote using JSch. I was looking at the RDP protocol and WMI protocol but they don't really look like they actually allow connection into the cmd to run commands. Is this just not a possibility on windows servers? Can I use a service to call WMIC?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that this is not a truly solved problem via a java library. The best thing I found for this appears to be to use [winexe](http://www.aldeid.com/wiki/Winexe#Common_options) and use java [Process](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html)